# If combobox text is empty don`t complete the action c#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have an problem that my code doesn`t work when i try to stop the code when comboBox index is not changed by user

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      {
            if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please complete the fields");
                return;
            }
        }
        {
            if (comboBox6.SelectedIndex == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please complete the fields");
                return;
            }
        }

        {
            pictureBox2.Image = Soccer_Studio.Properties.Resources.Default;
        }
        {
            if (comboBox6.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                Image newImage = Image.FromFile(@"Database\Logos\Competitions\BPL.png");
                RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(610.0F, 17.0F, newImage.Width, newImage.Height);
                g.DrawImage(newImage, rect);

                g.Flush();
                pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
            }
        }
     }
```

My Application is about that when a specific index is selected .. Draw an specific image
And if the combobox is empty .. Show a Messeage Box that show (Please complete the fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `SelectedIndex` is an `int`, so the following statement is *always* false, and the code inside of it will *never* execute:

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == null)
```

Instead, check for the value -1:

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
```

As a side note, since your title refers to the `ComboBox` text, you can also check the `Text` property:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text))
```

Comment: or Probably `comboBox2.SelectedIndex < 0`

Comment: LOL ... the comment was meant for OP; not for you. Though I have seen people do check for wither `> 0` or `< 0`

Comment: If you... like me, write programs for Stupid Users... You populate the first entry (0) with a message and then you do a check >0 on SelectedIndex with an else statement... Look at my reply below

Answer (score 0):

I would do this otherwise...

```
public Form1()
        {
          InitializeComponent();

            comboBox1.Items.Add("Please select an Item");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item1");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item2");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item3");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Item4");
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex= 0;
        }
```

and then If SelectedIndex == 0 refuse....

I think of the stupid users :)